# Find the range of $f(x)$

Tags: functions

if $$f(x)= {x^2-3x+c\over{(x+4)(x-1)}}$$ where domain is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1,-4\}$.
Then, find the range of the given function.
So, I tried this using the standard method as:

$y={x^2-3x+4\over {x^2+3x-4}}  \implies x^2y+3xy-4y=x^2-3x+4\implies x^2(1-y)+6xy-8y=0$

Now, for $x$ to be real, the discriminant must be $\geq 0$

Hence
$36y^2-4(1-y)(-8y)\geq 0,$

and by simplifying I got 
$y(y+8)\geq 0$

which gives

$y=(-\infty,-8] \cup [0,\infty),$

but the correct answer in my textbook is 
$(-\infty,-1]\cup\left[{7\over{25}},\infty\right)$

Comment: There are mistakes at the last equation of the first line. You mixed up the last two terms. The correct is: $(1-y)x^2-3(1+y)x+4(1+y)=0$

Comment: So, the $c$ in the formula for $f(x)$ should be a $4$?

Comment: We want to solve $y=\frac{x^2-3x+4}{x^2+3x-4}$ for $x$.Thus $x^2(y-1)+x(3y+3)=4y+4$.
We find that $$
x=\begin{cases}\dfrac86 &,\text{if}y=1;\\\pm\dfrac{-3y-3+\sqrt{25y^2+18y-7}}{2(y-1)} &,\text{if}y\neq1;\end{cases}$$
solves our equation. We want that $x$ is a real number, so $25y^2+18y-7\geq0$ should hold.
Note that $25y^2+18y$ is increasing on $[0,\infty[$ and decreasing on $]-\infty,-1]$.

Comment: Let's solve $25y^2+18y=7$:
\begin{equation}\begin{split}25y^2+18y\overset!=7&\iff y^2+\frac{18}{25}y+\frac{9^2}{25^2}\overset!=\frac7{25}+\frac{9^2}{25^2}\\&\iff\left(y+\frac9{25}\right)^2\overset!=7+\frac{9^2}{25^2}\\&\iff y=\frac7{25} \text{ or } y=-1.
\end{split}\end{equation}

Thus, $25y^2+18y-7\geq 0$ if and only if $y\in]-\infty,-1]\cup[\frac{7}{25},\infty[$. The latter set thus also corresponds to the range of your function.